# Get a non-const iterator from a const string parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, const-iterator

I am reading strings with the following syntax:

```
string example {"firstList:[element1:value1,element2:value2];secondList:[elementA:valueA,elementB:valueB]"};
```

Since a real list can have hundreds of elements, and I need only read operations (checking if `value1 == "something"` or if `elementA` exists), I implemented a `std::string::iterator` based function to find a list inside a given string. Here is a simplified version:

```
bool findList(
    const std::string &input,
    const std::string &listName,
    std::string::iterator globalStart,
    std::string::iterator globalEnd,
    std::string::iterator &listStart,
    std::string::iterator &listEnd
    )
{
    if (input.empty() || listName.empty()) return false;

    size_t inicio = input.find(listName);
    if (inicio == string::npos) return false;

    size_t fin = input.find("]", inicio);
    if (fin == string::npos) return false;

    listStart = globalStart + inicio + listName.length() + 2;
    listEnd = globalStart + fin;
    if (listEnd >= globalEnd) return false;

    string::iterator badList = std::find(listStart, listEnd, ';');
    if (badList != listEnd) return false;

    return true;
}
```

The function works, but I have to pass the string `input`, `input.begin()`, and `input.end()` to assign values for the list iterators. Is there another option to assign the `input.begin()` to `listStart` (and the same for `listEnd`)?

Writing:

```
    listStart = input.begin() + inicio + listName.length() + 2;
    listEnd = input.begin() + fin;
```

yields a compiler error for trying to assign a const iterator to a non-const iterator:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
  listStart = input.begin() + inicio + listName.length() + 2;
```

I am aware that passing the `input` only as `std::string &input` solves the problem, but I would like to keep the checks that `const` entails.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::size_t;

bool findList(
    const std::string &input,
    const std::string &listName,
    std::string::iterator globalStart,
    std::string::iterator globalEnd,
    std::string::iterator &listStart,
    std::string::iterator &listEnd
    )
{
    if (input.empty() || listName.empty()) return false;

    size_t inicio = input.find(listName);
    if (inicio == string::npos) return false;

    size_t fin = input.find("]", inicio);
    if (fin == string::npos) return false;

    listStart = globalStart + inicio + listName.length() + 2;
    listEnd = globalStart + fin;
    if (listEnd >= globalEnd) return false;

    string::iterator badList = std::find(listStart, listEnd, ';');
    if (badList != listEnd) return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {
    string example {"firstList:[element1:value1,element2:value2];secondList:[elementA:valueA,elementB:valueB]"};
    string::iterator listStart, listEnd;
    bool answer = false;

    // Test the findList function
    answer = findList(example, "firstList", example.begin(), example.end(), listStart, listEnd);
    assert(answer == true);
    assert(string(listStart, listEnd) == "element1:value1,element2:value2");
    cout << "Test firstList passed" << endl;

    answer = findList(example, "secondList", example.begin(), example.end(), listStart, listEnd);
    assert(answer == true);
    assert(string(listStart, listEnd) == "elementA:valueA,elementB:valueB");
    cout << "Test secondList passed" << endl;

    answer = findList(example, "thirdList", example.begin(), example.end(), listStart, listEnd);
    assert(answer == false);
    assert(string(listStart, listEnd) == "elementA:valueA,elementB:valueB"); // iterators remain unchanged
    cout << "Test thirdList passed" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

*This is my first question, please feel free to point out any improvement I could make to the post.

Comment: I can't reproduce the compiler error. Seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/1zWrWM).

Comment: I posted the version that compiles, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/cr88ed) reproduces the compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const std::string::iterator` means "iterator for a string, through which the string can be changed; the iterator can't be pointed anywhere else."

`std::string::const_iterator` means "iterator for a string, through which the string cannot be changed; the iterator can be pointed somewhere else."

It looks like you are confusing these two.  `input.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` when `input` is `const`, and you can't assign a `const_iterator` to an `iterator` -- that would break const-correctness.

All of your iterators in this function should be `const_iterator`.  Change your function signature to:

```
bool findList(
    const std::string &input,
    const std::string &listName,
    std::string::const_iterator globalStart,
    std::string::const_iterator globalEnd,
    std::string::const_iterator &listStart,
    std::string::const_iterator &listEnd
) {
    // ...
}
```

The caller should then use `str.cbegin()` and `str.cend()`.  Likewise, `listStart` and `listEnd` in `main()` should be changed to be `const_iterator`.